# Standing desk with ability to raise/lower?

Tags: automation

I have been wanting a better desk for many months. Pretty much my only requirements are:

- Desk must move up/down

  - Must have some sort of continuous mechanism for this (ie not just every 2 inches, etc)
  - Can be either motorized or non-motorized
- Must be available online
- Must have a flat surface that is reasonably rectangular

Price is meaningful, and I'd like to say less than $500, but this is not the most important thing. An ideal answer would include a few options with varying price ranges.

Comment: Do you have any requirements for the total surface area / dimensions of the desk?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about furniture, not about computing hardware.

Comment: Meta: http://meta.hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/50/107

Comment: Be sure to consider other alternatives, like a tall desk with a tall chair and a footrest. You can switch between sitting and standing in one second or less.

Answer (score 9):

### [Ergotron Workfit-D](http://www.ergotron.com/ProductsDetails/tabid/65/PRDID/631/language/en-US/Default.aspx)

[image: Ergotron Workfit-D]

<sup>Image source: ergotron.com</sup>

I do not (yet) own this desk, but I've put lots of research into this in hopes of soon owning a sit-stand desk. After evaluating quite a few desks, I've all but settled on the Workfit-D. It is non-motorized; the raising and lowering is enabled by Ergotron's "Patented Constant Force™ technology". That's a fancy term for "[spring powered](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A9044_iJ4S8)". The height adjustment is done by squeezing the handbrake on the front right corner of the desk then lifting.

#### Relevant Specifications

- **Capacity** — 65 lbs (29.5 kg)
- **Surface area** — Rectangular, 47.6" x 23.5" (121 cm x 60 cm)

  - If you'd like custom dimensions, Ergotron sells [just the base](http://www.ergotron.com/ProductsDetails/tabid/65/PRDID/757/language/en-US/Default.aspx). The maximum recommended dimensions are available on that product page. Note the difference in capacity; presumably the surface shipped with the Workfit-D is 23 lbs. IKEA sells [many different table tops](http://www.ikea.com/us/en/catalog/categories/departments/workspaces/18966/) in different sizes, shapes, and colors; you could go this route if you'd like some customization.
- **Vertical lift** — 20" (51 cm)
- **Minimum height** — 30.6" (78 cm)
- **Maximum height** — 50.6" (129 cm)
- **Price** — Currently [$689.00 with free shipping on Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B009MQTMF2)

#### Advantages

I initially was drawn to IKEA's [Bekant motorized sit/stand desk](http://www.ikea.com/us/en/catalog/products/S49022524/) due to the lower price, but two things dissuaded me: speed and stability. I've seen multiple reviewers report that at higher heights the Bekant is [not quite as stable as you might expect](https://youtu.be/xSsKpWAIJGQ?t=277). The Bekant also has a very slow height adjustment. Ergotron produced [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MnfSeoJcXvw) comparing their desk's rate of adjustment with one that is motorized. The video is a little silly but does a good job making a point.

#### Disadvantages

The Workfit-D does not have infinite height points. It uses locking pins to secure the desk at the height you select. I don't have information on the spacing between the pin holes but personally I would be happy with what's available based on the video reviews I've watched.

The minimum desk height is also a little high. My current static height sitting desk is roughly 28". I think I'd be comfortable with the 30.6" height, but it's a surprisingly high base for desk that has an adjustable height.

#### Helpful reviews

- [ENGLISH: ERGOTRON WORKFIT-D DESK 【HD】](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_7MDy2nzaq0)by Tecnologia Brasil
- [The Best Gaming Desk - Workfit-D Sit-Stand Desk Unboxing + Review](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h--HqeRRckA) by LevelCapGaming
- [Awesome Sit-Stand Desk by Ergotron](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RqueNvnhSwI) by Chris Davis

Answer (score 2):

Your best option would be to use the upliftdesk which is available online and has a motor to make it go up and down is made with quality materials has wire managment and it has a keyboard tray. It is $630 though. upliftdesk also has a frame only desk that is just a frame and has a motor already on it for $460 but it does not have a top so you would have to get one yourself.

Comment: Would be better if you attach a link to the product.

Comment: Why is this the best option?